# show live updates in d3 sankey chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I was trying d3 chart for visualizing the network flow from source to destination. I was trying with d3 sankey and the results were satisfying. I would like to update the sankey with the new values after every 5s. help from experts is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

http://bl.ocks.org/nl-hugo/c1a6c6f5b459449b9832d9f3ef73cb7d 
Looks like a good start for updating data in d3 sankey charts.

Just apply some vanilla JS interval of 5 seconds and you are good to go.